# CSS3 Transitions (How to make a pause?)

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to add the following functionality to this [CSS3PageTransitions](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3PageTransitions/index.html#contact) tutorial

How can I add a **Pause** time with a progress bar for 1 min between the page transitions.

So that the page goes away and the home page become visible for 1 min indicated by a progressbar then the next transition page appear.

Can this done without the use of Javascript?

Comment: What you're looking for (which isn't exactly clear) sounds like it should be done with javascript.

Comment: ok, thank you Wesley, i was hoping to get away without js! but there is no other solution then i think i got no other choice!

Comment: any leads on how it can be done?

Comment: Look up `setTimeout`, you can use it for both the progress bar and the page transition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout